# Get inserted id of table in postgresql with sequelize raw query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I do have postgresql with sequelize.
My need to get newly inserted id in table for insert statement. ( auto generated id / pk)

```
postgreFunctionservice.insertSavedFilter = async (appId, filterName, filterString, filterForPage) => {
  const query = `INSERT INTO sometable
        (company_id, filter_name, saved_filters, filter_for_page)
        VALUES ('${appId}', '${filterName}', '${filterString}', '${filterForPage}')`;
  const result = await sequelizDB.query(query, { returning : true });

  return result;
};
```

As we can see, I am using raw query for insert.
I am able to insert the record but not getting inserted id. I did lot of research but found noting useful. the "sequelize" version is "^6.3.5".

Any help would be really apricated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const query = `INSERT INTO sometable
        (company_id, filter_name, saved_filters, filter_for_page)
        VALUES ('${appId}', '${filterName}', '${filterString}', '${filterForPage}')`;
  const [id, ] = await sequelizDB.query(query, { returning : true });

  return id;
```

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/blob/9063c545f56e665995897320a21113bf0a5cd166/api/controllers/game.js#L12

Comment: it always give me  [ [], 1 ]

Answer (score 0):

For postgress, I needed RETURNING id included in the raw query.

```
postgreFunctionservice.insertSavedFilter = async (appId, filterName, filterString, filterForPage) => {
  const query = `INSERT INTO sometable
        (company_id, filter_name, saved_filters, filter_for_page)
        VALUES ('${appId}', '${filterName}', '${filterString}', '${filterForPage}') RETURNING ID`;
  const result = await sequelizDB.query(query, { returning : true });

  return result;
};
```